# Tkinter tutorial: checkbox always returns 0

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm doing a Tkinter tutorial on checkboxes and the provided code doesn't seem to work. When trying to get the value of a variable indicating whether the box is checked, it always returns 0, regardless of checked boxes.

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

def var_states():
   print("male: %d,\nfemale: %d" % (var1.get(), var2.get()))

Label(master, text="Your sex:").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="male", variable=var1).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(master, text="female", variable=var2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=var_states).grid(row=4, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Your code is working in my Windows box.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on OSX. By the way, the standard UI control for an exclusive choice (eg: male/female) is a radio button rather than a check button.

Comment: The code you shared is working as expected, maybe the issue is in the way/where you are checking the value. Please share that code as well to understand the problem.

Comment: @Kamal, I am only running the code posted. Using the "Show" button, the values contained in the checkbox variables are always 0.The problem appears to be with Enthought Canopy (with Python 3.5.2). Switching to Spyder (with Python 3.7) fixes the issue.